# Mobile Safari, Chrome crashes when upload pictures from camera

Tags: android, html, ios, google-chrome, mobile-safari

I have the simplest page: list of `<input type='file' accept='image/*'>`.

When do the following the simplest case:
- Hit "Upload"-> **take picture from camera** -> approve.
- Repeat it for all input conrols.(12 in my code below)
- Than i do it again and on ~15-th "upload" page crashed and was reloaded.

If to start the process again, the page crashes after 4-5th "upload". Finally, I can crash the page even after first picture upload.

The bug was described for **IPhone 6+ IOS 10.**

But I reproduced on **IPhone 6S+ IOS 10**(but only more iterations required,
**Iphone 6 IOS 10**, **Android Chrome 58.0.3029**.

***But works fine with iOS 9.5.3***

The Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
        .file-style {
            width: 20em;  height: 2em;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<input type='file' accept='image/*' class="file-style"><br>
<input type='file' accept='image/*' class="file-style"><br>
<input type='file' accept='image/*' class="file-style"><br>
<input type='file' accept='image/*' class="file-style"><br>
<input type='file' accept='image/*' class="file-style"><br>
<input type='file' accept='image/*' class="file-style"><br>
<input type='file' accept='image/*' class="file-style"><br>
<input type='file' accept='image/*' class="file-style"><br>
<input type='file' accept='image/*' class="file-style"><br>
<input type='file' accept='image/*' class="file-style"><br>
<input type='file' accept='image/*' class="file-style"><br>
<input type='file' accept='image/*' class="file-style"><br>

<script>

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

> PS. In real scenario I have SPA on react+redux where upload 4-6
>   images. And it fails after upload 4th, 5th image.

Answer (score 0):

The only way around is to not use `accept='image/*'` for these buggy browsers (or at all).

Just so that you know, using `image/gif, image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/png` won't solve your problem either.

Lastly, if mobile support is one of your goals, do understand that `accept` is not widely supported: https://caniuse.com/#search=accept